# Flux + Sinon + Promises test always passes or times out

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, flux

I am currently attempting to test Flux with Sinon + Sinon-As-Promised, but I am struggling to find relevant examples, and having an issue with my test always returning true, no matter the assertion.

My test currently looks like this:

```
    it('Form store should contain encounter object', function() {
    var stub = sinon.stub(restService, "loadForm").resolves(mockDataEncounter.Encounter);
    stub().then(function(value){
        console.log('Inside frmSrv');
        formStore._currentForm = value;
        expect(formStore._currentForm).to.have.property('Name');
    })
    console.log('calling action creator');
    actionCreator.loadForm("123456789012345678910003"); 
})
```

What I was expecting to happen was -

> Call action creator **->** Action creator usually makes the API call,
>   but in this case calls the stubbed method instead **->** Promise is
>   resolved, _currentForm is set to the mock data, and then the assertion
>   is checked.

However what actually happens is:

> Call action creator **->** Test passes **->** Promise resolves

If I add a done callback to the test, and then call done after the assertion, this causes things to execute in my expected order, but then if I modify the expected property to "Name1"(which doesnt exist), the test fails with a timeout error rather than the correct error to say the property doesnt exist.

Am I missing something fundamental here, or just going about things completely the wrong way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sinon but here's an article I wrote on testing promises with mocha http://catfish.life/testing-promises-with-mocha/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more fiddling I worked it out, I had to add a catch to the promise, and then call done passing in the error in order to get the correct failure message to display.

```
    it('Form store should contain encounter object', function(done) {
    var stub = sinon.stub(restService, "loadForm").resolves(mockDataEncounter.Encounter);
    stub().then(function(value){
        console.log('Inside frmSrv');
        formStore._currentForm = value;
        expect(formStore._currentForm).to.have.property('Name');
        done();
    }).catch(function(err){
        done(err);
    });

    console.log('calling action creator');
    actionCreator.loadForm("123456789012345678910003"); 
})
```